# Inno Setup: Keep position of desktop icon

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a way to persuade Inno Setup that after an "update" (full setup incl. uninstall of former version) the desktop icon gets its former position?

I hoped that I can start the uninstall setup with a parameter but I did not find anything.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#APPNAME_Messages}"; Filename: "{app}\{#Programm}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

The will always remove the icon when I uninstall the software. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Don't delete the icon on the automatic uninstall and don't re-create it on re-install, if its target is the same.

Comment: How can I avoid the deleting in the automatic uninstall?

Comment: Well, I would in the first place consider not uninstalling your application on upgrade at all. Why are you doing it?

Comment: As Martin says: Inno Setup supports upgrading without the need to uninstall first. Is there a specific reason you are uninstalling before the upgrade?

Comment: Clean and easy removal of some old and/or unwanted files or settings. I have a fullversion and an update version. Only the fullversion triggers the uninstall.

Comment: I'd instead remove the obsolete files as part of the installation.

Comment: If you use that approach, then the answer to your question is no, because you are removing the shortcut and creating it again.